# Can't get the value of a data PHP

Tags: php

im having trouble getting a result value of a query and the error says. 
`Notice: Undefined index: prelim in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingxworking\teacher\student.php on line 85` can someone help me to fix this or some clue to fix this? im just starting to learn php.

```
<tbody>
    <?php $c=1; ?>
    <?php foreach($mystudent as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $c; ?></td>    
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['studid']; ?></td>    
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['lname'].', '.$row['fname']; ?></td>  
            <?php $grade = $student->getstudentgrade($row['studid']);?>
            //code that cause error line 85-->  <td class="text-center"><?php echo $grade['prelim']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php $c++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if(!$mystudent): ?>
        <tr><td colspan="8" class="text-center text-danger"><strong>*** No Result ***</strong></td></tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

**the function:**

```
function getstudentgrade($studid){
    $q = "select * from studentsubject where studid=$studid";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    $data = array();
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
                $data[] = array(
        'prelim' => $row['prelim']
        );
    } 

    return $data;

}
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7 please start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: @SuperDJ yes i will change it.

Comment: Does your `studentsubject` table have a `prelim` column?

Comment: does your table has data for specific student id ?

Comment: @SuperDJ yes sir

Comment: @Ravi yes the table has a data.

Comment: for all `studid` ?

Comment: @ravi yes bro all has data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bara suggested, you need to check the array first before accessing it.

```
if(isset($grade['prelim']))
```

I suspect, there is no data for specific `studid`. Lets see you function.

```
$data = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
            $data[] = array(
    'prelim' => $row['prelim']
    );
}
```

Now, you have created new array `$data`. But, if there is no record ? your `while` loop won't be executed and your `$data` array won't have anything. right ? So, to handle that, you need to check whether there is any data in your array.

Now, second point, which @Mossavari made is also correct. You need to use

```
$grade[0]['prelim'];
```

instead of

```
$grade['prelim'];
```

Comment: Please go through my post completely. To avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Yes. I already edited and noted your suggestions and it worked sir.

Answer (score 0):

after doing

```
<?php $grade = $student->getstudentgrade($row['studid']);?>
```

you need to check what `$grade` holdes. and its better before trying to fetch data from array to make a check like this :

```
if(isset($grade['prelim']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your getstudentgrade function you'll have multidimensional array result, you may need to change

```
$grade['prelim']
```

to

```
$grade[0]['prelim']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, every student will have only 1 grade. So, why to use array.

```
<?php
function getstudentgrade($studid){
  $q = "select * from studentsubject where studid=$studid LIMIT 0,1";
  $data = "";
  $r = mysql_query($q);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
    $data = $row['prelim'];
  }
  return $data;
}?>
```

**PHP**

```
<tbody>
  <?php $c=1; ?>
  <?php foreach($mystudent as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $c; ?></td>    
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['studid']; ?></td>    
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['lname'].', '.$row['fname']; ?></td>  
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $grade = $student->getstudentgrade($row['studid']);?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $c++; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php if(!$mystudent): ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="text-center text-danger">
        <strong>*** No Result ***</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Because the grades is in different table. Actually inside that table it has two functions. The `$studid` is in different function so i need to get another function to get the grades.

Comment: I understood that. But, since every student is having only 1 grade. Then, why to use array for that @nethkennnnn

Comment: Then what to use sir? Im just starting to learn php and sql. And i don't know if this is a good practice. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem. See. Array is used only when there are multiple values. But, in your case, every student will have only 1 grade. So, what I'm trying to say is: why to use array for storing grades? @nethkennnnn